# Second controller for Modal Instance of Angular Bootstrap UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to define second template and controller for modal dialogue in Angular bootstrap UI.
But system return an error 
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemsProvider <- items <- newCtrl

http://embed.plnkr.co/lox1ZkU516NRL445v9el/preview

Any one has idea about what this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the object you're trying to resolve with - instead of `item` it should be `items`. The below function works ([fixed Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/dqfvoE/preview)):

```
$scope.openNew = function(size){
  var xmodal = $modal.open(
    {
     templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
     controller: 'newCtrl',
     resolve:{items: function(){return $scope.items;}}

    });

}
```